Issues with Device Communication in .NET MAUI Project: "External component has thrown an exception"
I'm encountering an issue with a .NET MAUI project that involves communicating with a device. The same code works fine in both Console and WPF applications, but fails in the .NET MAUI project.
I'm using the same communication library and dependencies across all applications. In the .NET MAUI project, the device scanning part works correctly using the main DLL, but it fails when attempting to instantiate an opened device object (CreateAndConnect in code snippet). The error message I'm receiving is: "External component has thrown an exception".
This exception occurs during a method call in the same DLL that successfully scanned for the device.
Here's a simplified version of the code that works when called from Console and WPF but fails when called from .NET MAUI:

    public virtual bool BindDevice(string serialNumber)
    {
            List<PvDeviceInfo> lDeviceInfos = new List<PvDeviceInfo>();
            lSystem.DetectionTimeout = 200;
            lSystem.Find();

            uint interfaceCount = lSystem.InterfaceCount;
            PvInterface lInterface;


            for (uint x = 0; x < interfaceCount; x++)
            {
                // Get pointer to each of interface.
                lInterface = lSystem.GetInterface(x);
                // Get the number of GigE Vision devices that were found using GetDeviceCount.
                uint lDeviceCount = lInterface.DeviceCount;
                for (uint y = 0; y < lDeviceCount; y++)
                {
                  var  lDeviceInfo = lInterface.GetDeviceInfo(y);
                    if (lDeviceInfo != null)
                    {
                       lDeviceInfos.Add(lDeviceInfo);
            }
            }
        }


        var lDeviceInfoID = lDeviceInfos.Where(di => di.UniqueID == serialNumber).First();

        if (("".Equals(serialNumber) ||lDeviceInfoID.UniqueID.Equals(serialNumber)))
        {
            try
            {
                lDevice = PvDevice.CreateAndConnect(lDeviceInfoID);

            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            { 
                Console.WriteLine(ex.ToString()); 
                return false; 
            }
        }
        return true;
    }



Environment:
.NET MAUI Project
Windows 10
.NET 7.0
Using 64-bit PvDotNet.dll and related dependencies
Has anyone encountered a similar issue with .NET MAUI projects? Any insights or solutions would be greatly appreciated.
I have investigated the deployment differences between .NET MAUI and other project types and verified that all provided libraries are copied to the running folder of the .NET MAUI application.
